# the controller is saving the image but the image cannot be found in the desired folder ..is my controller correct

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/room")

public class Roomcontroller {
@Autowired
private RoomService roomService;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(ModelMap map) throws SQLException {
    map.addAttribute("Room", roomService.getAll());
    return "admin/room/index";
}

   @RequestMapping(value = "/addroom", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String addRoom() throws SQLException {
    return "admin/room/addroom";
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/editroom/{ro_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView edit(@PathVariable("ro_id") int ro_id) throws SQLException {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("admin/room/editroom");
    mv.addObject("Room", roomService.getById(ro_id));
    return mv;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteroom/{ro_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String delete(@PathVariable("ro_id") int ro_id) throws SQLException {
    roomService.delete(ro_id);
    return "redirect:/admin/room";
}
```

this portion of the code is used for  saving image and other entities but I am not able to see the image stored in desired folder

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)

public String save(@RequestParam("roomType") String roomType,
@RequestParam("roomDescription") String roomDescription, @RequestParam("roomNumber") int roomNumber,
@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile, HttpServletRequest req) throws SQLException, IOException {

        Room room = new Room();
room.setRoom_type(roomType);
room.setRoom_description(roomDescription);
room.setRoom_number(roomNumber);

    // TO DO : Save room, fetch the id of saved room and set it through
    // setter in above object.

           if(room.getRo_id()==0){

    String serverRootPath = req.getServletContext().getRealPath("");
            System.out.println(serverRootPath);

    // You can change the directory.
    File roomImageDirectory = new File(serverRootPath + "D:\\Hotels\\ploadedImages");

    if (!roomImageDirectory.exists()) {
        roomImageDirectory.mkdirs();
    }
    String[] fileNameToken = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename().split("\\.");

    // You can change file name to be saved.
    String newFileName = "room-" + room.getRo_id() + "." + fileNameToken[fileNameToken.length - 1];

    File roomImage = new File(roomImageDirectory, "/" + newFileName);
    roomImage.createNewFile();
    multipartFile.transferTo(roomImage);
            room.setImage(newFileName);
            roomService.insert(room);  
        }

        else{
        roomService.update(room);
        }
return "redirect:/admin/room";  
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, you want to save your file under `D:\\Hotels\\ploadedImages`. So you don't need to use `req.getServletContext().getRealPath("")`. Just change your code like this

```
File roomImageDirectory = new File("D:\\Hotels\\ploadedImages");
...
File roomImage = new File(roomImageDirectory, "/" + newFileName);
```

I prefer `File.separator` instead of using `/` or `\\`

Comment: But it stores only one image but when I insert another image the previous is image is lost and a new image is stored instead

Comment: check your file name creation is correct or not if file name is the same then it gonna be overwrite

Comment: Thanks it helped alot ...ok one last question  I get error when I try to go for edit   org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT * FROM tbl_room WHERE ro_id = ?]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
root cause

Comment: This one is query error. So first check your table name and column name is correct or not. And check your query and check your id. I think you need to check the whole query.

Comment: I did checked the whole query it is working fine but when I press the edit but It just give same error I am not being able to figure it out can you please recheck my controller the edit portion

Comment: check your ro_id. It's may be null or incorrect value.

Comment: thanks alot I had missed passing ro_id in the while implementing

Comment: In the edit portion when I submit the form I get "HTTP Status 405 - Request method &#39;POST&#39; not supported"  why is that and even I am not able to update the image I just get choose file and empty  box

Comment: @NikilKaranjit Hi I'm not too clear what are you asking for? I think you should create new thread with necessary codes. This error can happen many possibilities. Are you using spring security?

Comment: do you have facebook or something so that I can connect with you and explain the problem

Comment: I have this in my debug log "Warning:   No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Hotels] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
Warning:   Request method 'POST' not supported when I try to update
" and the URL is "http://localhost:8080/Hotels/admin/room/editroom/save"

Answer (score -1):

probably you are constructing a wrong path

try,

```
String pathToUpload = req.getServletContext().getRealPath("/fileuploads");
File f = new File(pathToUpload);
if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { 
    f.mkdir();
}


String orgName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
String filePath = pathToUpload + orgName;
File dest = new File(pathToUpload);
file.transferTo(dest);
```

you should see file created inside root folder of your application context.